# Submit a form automatically - nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a website where a user `candidate` can submit an application for a job opening.

The `candidate` can see all the openings: http://localhost:3000/positions
[image: All openings]

I want the `candidate` to be able to click "apply" and directly submit an application.

For how it is now, If he clicks apply, he goes to a goes here: http://localhost:3000/positions/4/candidatures/new

This form is as follow:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="mt-5 offset-2 col-md-8">

    </div>
    <div id="my_candidature_form" class="my_candidature_form mt-3 offset-2 col-md-8">
      <%= simple_form_for [@position, @candidature] do |f| %>

        <%= f.submit "Submit ", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

It **does already contain all the params I want the user to send**, in fact the **candidatures_controller.rb** is:

```
  def new
    @position = Position.find(params[:position_id])
    @candidature = Candidature.new
  end


  def create
    @position = Position.find(params[:position_id])
    @candidature = Candidature.new

    @candidature.candidate = current_candidate
    @candidature.position = @position
    @candidature.interviewer = @position.interviewer
    if @candidature.save
      redirect_to position_path(@position)
      flash[:success] = "You applied"
    else
      redirect_to position_path(@position)
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong, try again"
    end
raise
  end
```

**I WOULD LIKE** that the user, once clicks "apply" in http://localhost:3000/positions submits also the form for http://localhost:3000/positions/4/candidatures/new.

I tried with javascript and ajax:
**candidature/new.html.erb**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
  url: $('#my_candidature_form').attr('action'),
  success: function(data){
    alert(data.ip);
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('failure');
  }
});
});
</script>
```

**OR**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
$(#my_candidature_form).submit();
});
</script>
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, define this form in `/positions` (for each job I think we need different form... here I'm providing instruction for a single job, I hope you'll manage to define this for all jobs :) )

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="mt-5 offset-2 col-md-8">
    <div id="my_candidature_form" class="my_candidature_form_1 mt-3 offset-2 col-md-8">
      <%= simple_form_for [@position, @candidature] do |f| %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Yes, without `f.submit`.

Then define that `apply` button like this (again, for each job we need different apply button):

```
<%= link_to 'Apply', "#", class: 'btn-apply-now form-1' %>
```

And write some script to setup event for that `apply` button like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn-apply-now.form-1').on('click', function () {
    $(#my_candidature_form_1).submit();
  });
});
</script>
```

That's it! Now, I hope it'll work :)